# Unable to get rid of Firefox focus display in radios and checkboxes

Tags: css, firefox

[image]

I'm trying to get rid of a blue focus outline in Firefox. When I set outline to 0 or none, nothing happens. If I set outline to something else, a separate outline appears (in the example it is a square green one). I also tried using a box shadow.
But if I try to remove or modify the border, nothing happens. (I can't make a separate border or remove the automatic outline) In the example I even tried using an inline style with !important. When I run the snippet in the editor in Firefox the focus outline shows up straight away.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#test').focus();
});
```

```css
[type=radio]:focus {
        box-shadow:1px 1px 4px red;
        outline:1px solid green;
        border:0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="question-preview2" /> 1<br>
<input id="test" type="radio" name="question-preview2" /> 2<br>
<input style="border:none !important;" type="radio" name="question-preview2" /> 3<br>
```

Edit:
-moz-appearance:none; almost fixes it... but the radio still appears a bit different (has a sunken appearance)

```js
$(function(){
    $('#test').focus();
});
```

```css
input:focus{-moz-appearance:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="radio" name="question-preview2" /> 1 <- has sunken appearance<br>
<input type="radio" name="question-preview2" /> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="question-preview2" /> 3<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ::-moz-focus-inner, then you don't need to specify the :focus pseudo selector. This worked for me.

Comment: I just tried "::-moz-focus-inner{outline:none;border:none;}" but it didn't seem to work. You can copy the snippet to your answer to try it out.

Comment: There is also this other nonstandard CSS pseudo selector you can try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-focusring

Some combination of these selectors should do the trick if you format your selector properly. For instance, with the selector in my original answer, you'd need to do `input::moz-focus-inner` and then remove any outlines and box shadows.

Here is a link to the selector from above too: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/button-padding-issue/.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be possible. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12847487/949217) (along with the one immediately following it) explain why it's not possible.